# Can't think of a name for a rhetorical figure

Tags: terminology, rhetoric

I have a feeling there's a name for a rhetorical figure, or perhaps a misuse of language, along the following lines:

> He went out to get drunk, and the mail.

In other words I'm looking for a term that describes what you do when you (for example) use a verb with what looks like a compound object, but one of the words isn't really an object but a word the verb governs in some quite different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an example of *[syllepsis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syllepsis#Noun)*:

> (rhetoric) A figure of speech in which one word simultaneously modifies two or more other words such that the modification must be understood differently with respect to each modified word; often causing humorous incongruity

For more examples and discussion, see
• [Using verbs with multiple meanings](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/34250),
• [Stop if you feel faint or pain!](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/58907) [duplicate],
• [She was carrying twins and a bulky bag in her hands](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/97370) [duplicate],
• [Is this sentence semantically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/97809)

Also see the wikipedia *[zeugma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma)* article, which distinguishes Type 1, Grammatical Syllepsis (or, *zeugma*) from Type 2, Semantic Syllepsis (or, *syllepsis*), giving as examples of Type 1,

> • He works his work, I mine. (Tennyson, “Ulysses”)
>   • They saw lots of thunder and lightning. [Can't *see* thunder]

and of Type 2,

> • Miss Bolo [...] went straight home, in a flood of tears and a sedan-chair. (Charles Dickens, The Pickwick Papers, Chapter 35)
>   • You are free to execute your laws and your citizens as you see fit. (Star Trek: The Next Generation)
>   • When he asked "What in heaven?" she made no reply, up her mind, and a dash for the door. (Flanders and Swann, Have Some Madeira M'Dear) ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_Some_Madeira_M%27Dear),[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OW_zi8n4HDQ),[3](http://members.optusnet.com.au/pennywyatt/Interests/FlandersSwann/DropOfaHat/At%20the%20Drop%20of%20a%20Hat11.html),[4](http://www.creekcats.com/pnprice/Madeira.html))